# How can I install a project's transitive dependencies in a custom local repository when using parallel threads in maven invoker

Tags: maven, maven-3, integration-testing

I am using maven-invoker-plugin to run about 20 integration tests.  I want to use parallel threads, and that's trivial to do - just add the appropriate configuration element.

My problem is that I'm using an isolated custom local repository.  When I run the tests synchronously, the first one takes 130 seconds or so, as it downloads the full set of maven plugins and other pieces needed to execute the build.  The remainder are about 5-10 seconds each.  When I add parallelThreads=5 (for instance), then the first five of my tests run in parallel, but all install the same dependency graph.

I attempted to use the  to have a project which is run first, and which would effectively prime the local repository shared by all the integration tests.

No luck. If I go parallelThreads=5, I get my setup project plus for others, all running at the same time. What i want, is a way to have such a setup project run ahead of all others, even with the parallel threads being plural.

I have experimented with .  However, this requires that I list, explicitly, every artifact at every version, the artifacts to install, and the transitive dependencies are not computed (it seems).  I end up needing to manage a very brittle list of dependencies.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a good way for me to fulfill at least the plugin dependencies from the "real" local repository, since none of those are what I'm building.  I just don't want to download the world again for each invoker run, while still maintaining an isolated test environment.

Comment: If you only need to use a local repositroy would `mvn -o` ([Work offline](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-offline-option)) be a solution to your problem?

Comment: Sadly not.  When I say use a local repo, I mean use a custom, fresh local repo that isn't the user's current one, so the tests themselves aren't contaminated by bad versions of the system under test that might be in the user's local repo.  It's an isolation thing.  -o merely tells maven that it should not try to resolve over the network, and take everything from the current local repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration of the maven-invoker-plugin has an opportunity to run [setupIncludes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/prepare-build-env.html) but unfortunately there is currently a [bug in maven-invoker-plugin which exactly failes in the situation](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MINVOKER-147).

But you can get around that by using the [extraArtifact](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/install-mojo.html#extraArtifacts) configuration like this:

```
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-integration-tests</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>install</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <extraArtifacts>
            <extraArtifact>junit:junit:4.8:jar</extraArtifact>
            <extraArtifact>com.soebes.maven.plugins:maven-echo-plugin:0.1:maven-plugin</extraArtifact>
            <extraArtifact>org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit4:2.10:jar</extraArtifact>
            <extraArtifact>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:maven-plugin</extraArtifact>
            <extraArtifact>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:maven-plugin</extraArtifact>
            <extraArtifact>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:maven-plugin</extraArtifact>
            <extraArtifact>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:maven-plugin</extraArtifact>
            <extraArtifact>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:maven-plugin</extraArtifact>
            <extraArtifact>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:maven-plugin</extraArtifact>
          </extraArtifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
```

So you can define all dependencies which are needed during the integration tests. Either are plugins or usual dependencies.

Comment: So, I've already played with extraArtifacts.  That's sort of the point of the post.  If I use extraArtifacts, I have to specify every single artifact I want to prime, and every plugin artifact for that build, and that is incredibly laborious to maintain, and a change in maven version used to build can invalidate the list.  It's a brittle thing in a system designed around an automatic handling of the transitive dependency set.

Comment: But thank you for the bug note.  I did not realize there is a current issue in the invoker plugin.

Comment: It will handle transitive dependencies so you only define a plugin for example and everything will be downloaded. For other dependencies it works the same way. I know it's not really convenient but it works till the time the bug is fixed ;-)

Comment: Yep.  the bug described is the issue I'm facing.  Thanks.  I consider this answered.  I will dig into the issue on the maven side.  Thanks!